# Can a lead-acid battery charger be used for "Gel" type?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, battery-chemistry

I have a [PB-600-24](http://www.meanwell.com/search/PB-600/default.htm) lead acid battery charger.

Can I use it for the battery type that has an image as below? 4 of the batteries are in series.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnFh7.jpg]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes a gel battery is just another name for sealed lead acid battery or [SLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VRLA_battery) and your charger clearly states that it is capable of charging sealed lead acid batteries

Comment: There's really no such thing as a "sealed" lead acid battery.  Your link is to Wikipedia VRLA definition - Valve Regulated Lead Acid is the technically correct term for this type of battery.  A safety valve is used to vent offgassing to prevent explosion on overcharge.

Comment: Yeah I know, I just figure I would call it by the more popular name since a lot more people would understand it that way.. plus also the charger datasheet called it so..

Comment: There *is* such a thing as a sealed battery. Unsealed wet cell batteries are open to the atmosphere with a drain tube. Sealed lead acid batteries are actually sealed air-tight and have a valve to vent if the pressure gets too high. There is a difference because wet cell batteries evaporate all the time whereas a sealed battery does not. It really is a seal.